# Перекомпиляция шейдера

Tags: opengl

Вопрос по Apple GLKit.

Вопрос касаемо перекомпиляции шейдера. `prepareToDraw` по необходимости перекомпилирует шейдер. У нас подозрение, что это является причиной проблем с производительностью. С другой стороны, необходимости перекомпиляции (там, где мы наблюдаем проблемы с производительностью) мы не видим. Необходимо понимание, что является триггером для перекомпилляции и можем ли мы как-то на это влиять. Главный подвопрос - принуждает ли смена текстур (вопрос 1) к перекомпиляции (сейчас очень похоже, что так происходит).